# SQLAlchemy: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a weird problem.
I have a simple py3 app, which uses sqlalchemy.

But several hours later, there is an **error:**

> (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

My init part:

```
self.db_engine = create_engine(self.db_config, pool_pre_ping=True) # echo=True if needed to see background SQL
Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.db_engine)
self.db_session = Session()
```

The query (this is the only query that happens):

```
while True:
    device_id = self.db_session.query(Device).filter(Device.owned_by == msg['user_id']).first()
    sleep(20)
```

The whole script is in infinite loop, single threaded (SQS reading out). Does anybody cope with this problem?

Comment: Keeping a session alive for an infinite period is a bad idea.  As the interval between sessions is 20 seconds - a long time in database connection terms - I'd create a new session for each iteration.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try, and I'll write back.

Comment: Relative to connections, sessions are quite efficient to create so you don't need to be concerned with them having a short life-cycle. The SQLAlchemy engine maintains a connection pool for you so each session is not making a new connection to the database, just establishing a new transaction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution:
don't let your connection open a long time.
SQLAlchemy documentation also shares the same solution: [session basics](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html)

```
@contextmanager
    def session_scope(self):
        self.db_engine = create_engine(self.db_config, pool_pre_ping=True) # echo=True if needed to see background SQL        
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.db_engine)
        session = Session()
        try:
            # this is where the "work" happens!
            yield session
            # always commit changes!
            session.commit()
        except:
            # if any kind of exception occurs, rollback transaction
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
```

Comment: Is it possible to maintain connections by SQLAlchemy, not by the user, now I do not know where not close the connection cause this problem. @mkiss